# How to run and kill an asynchronous redirect using ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, linux, unix

I want to re-direct the output of a command to a text file, and I want to run the command using [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) (on Linux or Unix). I want the redirect to run asynchronously, and I want the Java process to store the pid of the redirect command, and kill the redirect process when the redirect is no longer required.

I see that `ProcessBuilder.start()` returns a [Process](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) object which has the method `Proccess.pid()`. I also see a method `Process.waitFor()` implying to me that the redirect command is inherently asynchronous when run via `Process Builder`.

So my question is, can I run a redirect command in an asynchronous process using `ProcessBuilder`, get the PID with `Process`, and kill the running redirect process down the line all by omitting `Process.waitFor()`? Is that entirely possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the [`Process`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) class has [`destroy()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#destroy--) and [`destroyForcibly()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#destroyForcibly--) methods to kill the running process. Starting in Java 9 the [`ProcessHandle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessHandle.html) class was added which also has methods of the same name.

If you have the pid but don't have the `Process` object, you can get a `ProcessHandle` for a running process given its pid using the [`ProcessHandle.of(long pid)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessHandle.html#of-long-) method but if you started the `Process` yourself it is easier to just use the `Process` object that was returned from `ProcessBuilder.start()` or get the `ProcessHandle` from it using the [`Process.toHandle()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#toHandle--) method.